# Update Boundary conditions during simulation

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, dymola

In my Modelica co-simulation, I need to dynamically update the boundary conditions of the model based on another model that is not an FMU. Currently, I'm reading the boundary conditions from a text file using "CombiTimeTable". However, this text file gets updated during the co-simulation.

It appears that Modelica reads the text file only once at the beginning of the simulation. Is there a way to force Modelica to re-read the text file every time a "when" statement is triggered?

I tried extending the "CombiTimeTable" to be able to read the data in every "when" statement, but failed.

Comment: Would making the boundary conditions inputs to the model be an option? Then the output of the one model could be the input to the other model.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Modelica Standard Tables (with [CombiTimeTable](https://doc.modelica.org/Modelica%204.0.0/Resources/helpDymola/Modelica_Blocks_Sources.html#Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable)) have been designed with exactly this update-use-case in mind. Unfortunately, it was obsoleted, but still works via [ObsoleteModelica4.Blocks.Tables.Internal.readTimeTableData](https://doc.modelica.org/ObsoleteModelica4%204.0.0/Resources/helpDymola/ObsoleteModelica4_Blocks_Tables_Internal.html#ObsoleteModelica4.Blocks.Tables.Internal.readTimeTableData) (in non-pedantic mode). Here's a minimal example:

```
model TableUpdate
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable combiTimeTable(
    tableOnFile=true,
    tableName="a_tab",
    fileName=Modelica.Utilities.Files.loadResource("modelica://Modelica/Resources/Data/Tables/test.txt"),
    columns=2:2)
    annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-60,60},{-40,80}})));
equation 
  when sample(0, 1) then
    // tableID is a protected component of CombiTimemTable (and shoud not be accessed)
    ObsoleteModelica4.Blocks.Tables.Internal.readTimeTableData(combiTimeTable.tableID, true, true);
  end when;
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0"), ObsoleteModelica4(version="4.0.0")), 
    experiment(StopTime=100));
end TableUpdate;
```

**Update 20th Nov 2023:**

There now is ModelicaTableAdditions.Blocks.Sources.FileUpdateTimeTable availabe in [ModelicaTableAdditions](https://github.com/tbeu/ModelicaTableAdditions) that solves the issue with protected component access and obsoleted functions. Here's the updated example:

```
model TableUpdate2
  ModelicaTableAdditions.Blocks.Sources.FileUpdateTimeTable fileUpdateTimeTable(
    tableName="a_tab",
    fileName=Modelica.Utilities.Files.loadResource("modelica://Modelica/Resources/Data/Tables/test.txt"),
    forceRead=true)
    annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-60,20},{-40,40}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.BooleanExpression booleanExpression(y=sample(0, 1))
    annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-78,52},{-58,72}})));
equation 
  connect(fileUpdateTimeTable.updateTrigger, booleanExpression.y)
    annotation(Line(points={{-50,42},{-50,62},{-57,62}}, color={255,0,255}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0"), ModelicaTableAdditions(version="2.3.0")), 
    experiment(StopTime=100));
end TableUpdate2;
```

Comment: Thanks! I loaded the library ObsoleteModelica4 and I am trying to run this example with OpenModelica 1.21.0~2-g0bc3d29 . When I run the example I get an error


'[1] 15:50:13 Translation Error
[Modelica.Blocks.Sources: 1617:5-1628:78]: Illegal access of protected element tableID.'

'[2] 15:50:13 Translation Error
[readread2: 11:5-11:99]: Variable combiTimeTable.tableID not found in scope TableUpdate'

Comment: I updated the answer and example to fix the mentioned limitations.

Comment: This works. Just what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
model Unnamed1
  discrete Real a[2,2](start=zeros(2,2));
equation 
  when sample(0,1) then
    if time<0.5 then
      a = Modelica.Utilities.Streams.readRealMatrix("A1.mat", "data", 2, 2);
    else
      a = Modelica.Utilities.Streams.readRealMatrix("A2.mat", "data", 2, 2);
    end if;
  end when;

  annotation (experiment(StopTime=1.5, __Dymola_Algorithm="Dassl"));
end Unnamed1;
```

A1.mat and A2.mat were created as follows:

```
a = [1,2;3,4];
writeMatrix("A1.mat","data",a);
writeMatrix("A2.mat","data",a*2);
```

Possibly you need a new name for the .mat file every time, I did not check this.

Comment: Thanks!!
Now, I would like to assign this value to `Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature`. However, it seems that the only possible input for this object is `parameter` and not `discrete`. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: You could use Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.PrescribedTemperature and set the input to the discrete variable "a".

Comment: worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For interest this also works:

```
model Test
  discrete Real a[2,2](start=zeros(2, 2));
equation 
  when sample(0, 1) then
    Claytex.Functions.System.sleep(10000, time);
    a = Modelica.Utilities.Streams.readRealMatrix(
      "A.mat",
      "data",
      2,
      2);
  end when;
end Test;
```

Where Claytex.Functions.System.sleep is a pause function that gives enough time for A.mat to be modified using a different instance of Dymola.

A.mat was created as follows:

```
a = [1,2;3,4];
writeMatrix("A.mat","data",a);
```

and during the pause

```
writeMatrix("A.mat","data",a*2);
```

Comment: Not sure, why sleep is necessary here at all. But apart from that, the model misses the uses annotation of the Claytex library which is not generally available. Why not using Modelica_DeviceDrivers.OperatingSystem.sleep?